# Problema al cargar fragments: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id

Tags: android, android-fragment

Tengo un inconveniente al cargar los fragments.
Tengo un activity que carga el primer fragment y este activity contiene un FrameLayout con un contenedor (+id/placeholderfragments) con los fragments.
Al iniciar la activity se carga el primer fragment.
Cada fragment tiene dos botones siguiente y atrás.

Cuando hago click en el botón siguiente del primer fragment debería cargar el segundo fragment.
Cuando hago click en el botón siguiente del segundo carga el tercero, etc.

El primer fragment carga bien.
Pero cuando quiero navegar al segundo fragment, haciendo click en el button siguiente, tengo un error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0800e4 (com.example.aprendelastablasdemultiplicar:id/placeholderfragments) for fragment explicaciontablas2{e01499a} (8470d420-1680-4dc2-a33e-79362b842ebe) id=0x7f0800e4}
```

Este es el código del xml de la activity

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".quesonlastablas"
        android:orientation="vertical">



    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/placeholderfragments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <fragment
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           class="com.example.aprendelastablasdemultiplicar.explicaciontablas1"
           android:id="@+id/explicaciontablas1"/>

        <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.example.aprendelastablasdemultiplicar.explicaciontablas2"
            android:id="@+id/explicaciontablas2"/>

        <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.example.aprendelastablasdemultiplicar.explicaciontablas3"
            android:id="@+id/explicaciontablas3"/>

        <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.example.aprendelastablasdemultiplicar.explicaciontablas4"
            android:id="@+id/explicaciontablas4"/>

        <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.example.aprendelastablasdemultiplicar.explicaciontablas5"
            android:id="@+id/explicaciontablas5"/>

        <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.example.aprendelastablasdemultiplicar.explicaciontablas6"
            android:id="@+id/explicaciontablas6"/>

        <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.example.aprendelastablasdemultiplicar.explicaciontablas7"
            android:id="@+id/explicaciontablas7"/>

        <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.example.aprendelastablasdemultiplicar.explicaciontablas8"
            android:id="@+id/explicaciontablas8"/>

        <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.example.aprendelastablasdemultiplicar.explicaciontablas9"
            android:id="@+id/explicaciontablas9"/>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Y cada fragment tiene el siguiente código Java que reemplaza el fragment por el fragment siguiente:

```
    package com.example.aprendelastablasdemultiplicar;


    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
    import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
    import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;





    /**
     * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
     * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
     * {@link explicaciontablas1.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
     * to handle interaction events.
     * Use the {@link explicaciontablas1#newInstance} factory method to
     * create an instance of this fragment.
     */
    public class explicaciontablas1 extends Fragment {
        private Button siguiente;
        private Button atras;
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

        // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
        // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;


public explicaciontablas1() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment explicaciontablas1.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static explicaciontablas1 newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    explicaciontablas1 fragment = new explicaciontablas1();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);


    }


}






@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_explicaciontablas1, container, false);




Button siguiente = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.siguiente);
Button atras = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.atras);


if (savedInstanceState == null){


    siguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Fragment explicacion2 = new explicaciontablas2();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.placeholderfragments, explicacion2);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();


    }
});

atras.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Fragment explicacion2 = new explicaciontablas2();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.placeholderfragments, explicacion2);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        buttonClickSound();
    }
});
}

return rootView;


}

public void buttonClickSound(){
    buttonClickSoundStop();
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.siguientemultiplicar);
    mediaPlayer.start();
}

private void buttonClickSoundStop(){
    if (mediaPlayer != null){
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
}


// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}


@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}


/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

El problema se debe a que al cargar el Fragment `explicaciontablas1` tienes un elemento con id `placeholderfragments` pero al realizar el reemplazo a el Fragment `explicaciontablas2` este ya no existe.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0800e4
> (com.example.aprendelastablasdemultiplicar:id/placeholderfragments)
> for fragment explicaciontablas2{e01499a}
> (8470d420-1680-4dc2-a33e-79362b842ebe) id=0x7f0800e4}

Al parecer dentro de `fragment_explicaciontablas1.xml` no existe `placeholderfragments` y eso es lo que causa el problema.

Comment: placeholderfragments es el FrameLayout que contiene a los fragments... está en la activity quesonlastables.class.. qué raro antes funcionaba y ahora no funciona más... tendré que incluir placeholderfragments en explicaciontablas1? Como un frame layout??

Answer (score -1):

El problema que tienes es que estas sustituyendo el FrameLayout
"placeholderfragments" por ejemplo en las linea como esta:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.placeholderfragments, explicacion2);
```

Y al hacer esto todo el FrameLayout se reemplaza por el fragment "explicacion2", en este punto se pierden todos los Fragments que tienes dentro del FrameLayout y por ello al iniciar se carga el fragment pero luego te sale el error.

Te recomiendo que uses solo un Fragment dentro del FrameLayout y éste sea el que cambies por ejemplo:

Activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".quesonlastablas"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/placeholderfragments"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <fragment
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/explicacionTablas"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

y en el codigo reemplaces el Fragment "explicacionTablas" de la siguiente forma:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.explicacionTablas, explicacion2);
```

Nota: Cada clase de "ExplicacionTablas" debe tener un layout independiente , debes crear uno por cada explicación y en su onCreate debe hacer referencia a su respectivo layout